# как лучше организовать хранение данных в clickhouse

Tags: хранение-данных, clickhouse

мы используем clickhouse для хранения аналитических срезов данных. как частный пример - таблица с клиентами. Клиент это иерархичная сущность с несколькими ветвями (например: список адресов клиента, список договоров клиента и т.д.). Сейчас сделано таким образом, что в случае если у нас 2 адреса и 2 договора - вместо 1 строчки в таблице олицетворяющей клиента у нас получается 4:

```
|клиент|договор|адрес|  
|петров|1|полюстровский 11|  
|петров|1|гражданский 12|  
|петров|2|полюстровский 11|  
|петров|2|гражданский 12|
```

есть мысль перенести информацию о договорах и адреса в колонку с массивом значений, вопрос - насколько это оптимальнее? не умрем ли мы при поиске значения по столбцу/массиву? например при типовой задаче - поискать всех клиентов с адресом похожим на "%полюстровский%".